# set multiple redirect route path in vue

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

```
const router = new VueRouter({
routes: [
      {path: '*', redirect: '/'}
      }
)}
```

I have set this as redirect route in routes.js file.
how i can set more than 1 redirect path and call it on particular condition

Comment: What do you mean? Provide some examples.

Comment: can i set two path as redirected in routes.js or how i can redirect path pro-grammatically in method?

Comment: router.push : http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

In the component you want to set multiple redirects based on a condition you can use `beforeRouteEnter()` property in that component like below:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to,from,next){
    next(vm => {
        if(condition 1){
            vm.$router.push('the path you want to redirect');
        }else if(condition 2){
            vm.$router.push('the path you want to redirect');
        }else{
            //no redirect
            next();
        }
    });
}
```

Since the vue instance is not yet created when `beforeRouteEnter()` property is called you cannot use `this` to access the vue instance and follow the process the method shown above via `vm`

Another way would be by using [route meta feilds](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/meta.html) where you would include a meta field when defining a route and checking for a meta field in the global navigation guard. In that global navigation guard you can redirect by checking various `if` statements.